# How could I make my media queries better?

Tags: responsive-design, media-queries

I'm trying to create a responsive image wall - CSS only. Each image is the background (background-size:cover) of a float:left li.

Example here : http://www.tourdumonde.fr/dev/tiles.php

My goal is to be able to adjust li width depending on screen width.

**I want to be able to display :**

IF ON ANY SMARTPHONE (portrait and landscape) : 2 li per row (float:left; width:50%; min-height:300px; )

ELSE (any other device) :

- 2 li per row if screen width < 481px
- 3 li per row if screen width < 600px
- 4 li per row if screen width < 767px
- 5 li per row if screen width < 1100px

Here are my media queries :

```
ul, ul li { margin:0; padding:0; list-style-type:none; }
ul { width:100%; }
li { float:left; overflow:hidden; background-size:100% auto; border:none;}

/* LAPTOP / DESKTOP RULES */
@media (max-width: 480px) {
li { width:100%; min-height:300px;}
}
@media (min-width: 481px) {
li { width:50%; min-height:175px;}
}
@media (min-width: 600px) {
li { width:33%; min-height:150px;}
}
@media (min-width: 767px) {
li { width:25%; min-height:150px;}
}
@media (min-width: 1100px) {
li { width:20%;min-height:150px; }
}

/* SMARTPHONES RULE */
@media (orientation: portrait) and (max-device-width: 360px), (orientation: landscape)     and (max-device-width: 640px) {
li { width:50%; min-height:310px;}
}
```

For now, i tried and tested it on laptop (IE, Firefox, Chrome) by resizing to test how it adjusts : seems to work rather ok.

I also tested on my Samsung Galaxy S3 (Chrome), and I do get my 2-per-row lis.

But I feel the logic of my media queries could be improved (this is the first time I ever use them, so i'm pretty sure they are clumsy).

**=> How could I make these media queries more efficient ? Do you see any drawback in there ? IS the rule for smartphones versatile enough ?**

*(for now, I noticed a "bug" : when on smartphone (SGS3) : if I load the page in landscape mode, I get my 2 per row li. but if i change orientation, it autoresize to 4 per row. I have to refresh to make it 2 per row again)*

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best way to achieve this *(and the way I've been doing it)* is by using [column-count](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/columns/). Here's an example:

```
ul { line-height: 0; width:100%; margin:0 auto;
   -webkit-column-count: 5;
   -webkit-column-gap:   0px;
   -moz-column-count:    5;
   -moz-column-gap:      0px;
   column-count:         5;
   column-gap:           0px;
}

li img { width:100% !important; height:auto !important; }

@media (max-width: 767px) { ul {   -moz-column-count:4; -webkit-column-count:4; column-count:4; } }
@media (max-width: 600px) { ul {   -moz-column-count:3; -webkit-column-count:3; column-count:3; } }
@media (max-width: 481px) { ul {   -moz-column-count:2; -webkit-column-count:2; column-count:2; } }
```

*Edit: The reason your columns are off in landscape mode is probably because you forgot to include the viewport meta.*

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Edit edit: The bug might be fixed by applying this code instead of the regulair body tag.

```
<body onload="resize()" onresize="resize()">
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your contribution. Just so that I can further understand, why do you think this approach is better than using floating lis ? Regarding my media queries, do you see any way I could "chain" them a better way ?

Comment: With column count the list items automaticly fill in the blank spacing with percentages. There's no calculation involved. (In your approach you need to recalculate the amount of percentage for every media-query. I just set a new column-count.) Also, as you can see in your example, when I resize the screen and get to three columns, the images in the middle row get cut off.

Comment: This is okay if you wish to maintain a static block with a hidden overflow, but not if you wish to display every image in it's fullest. Your approach is fine since it gets the job done. My approach is just an alternative, wich always keeps my images in proportions. Also; I think I've found a solution for your bug. Check the second edit in my answer.

Comment: Hey Jefferson, with a bit of delay, thank you for your explanations, it was crystal clear and helped me a lot.